# How dangerous is it to use runModalForWindow from multiple threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, modal-dialog

I have a memory corruption error (I suspect), which is resulting in a program crash after specific UI actions. This is a Cocoa Objective-C application and does not use GC.

After many hours of debugging, I found a possible reason for the crash:

```
DiscSelectPopup *popupSelect = [[DiscSelectPopup alloc] initWithDataList:dataList count:count];     
NSInteger result = [NSApp runModalForWindow:popupSelect.window];
```

The above popup routine is executed from a secondary thread. This thread is created and started every time the user clicks on a button. So, we can have several modal popup show up simultaneously.

When I run the program in debug mode with `MallocStackLogging=1` and `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=1`, it prints a malloc error log message at the `runModalForWindow:` call (but not always).

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xbc65840: double free
.....
malloc: *** error for object 0xbc547e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Is it really bad to use `runModalForWindow:` from a secondary thread?
Could it be the reason for the crash?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using valgrind memcheck, I concluded that the secondary thread `runModalForWindow:` calls are not directly connected with the memory corruption problem.

Yes, it is bad coding to manipulate UI components from non-main threads but such behavior alone cannot crash the program.

The malloc error message in the question was due to the mistakenly double released popup window object.

By the way, real cause of the memory corruption was the mismatched malloc/free call (freeing not malloced memory pointer).

Comment: You may be the correct about the source of this particular crash, but you are definitely incorrect in your dismissal of the seriousness of UI manipulation from a secondary thread. You *can* cause major problems and even crashes by modifying the UI from a secondary thread. You should read the [Thread Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html).

Comment: Thanks! It is a really helpful document.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it really bad to use `runModalForWindow` from the secondary thread?

Yes. UI stuff needs to happen on the main thread.

You also shouldn't use `runModalForWindow:` unless you specifically want to block all of the other windows in your application (essentially freezing your app except for that window). Just show the window. If you want to block a specific window (or your app is single-window), begin it as a sheet.

Edit: Looking again at the question, this caught my eye:

> The above popup routine is executed from a secondary thread.

Don't do that. To show a window, just show it. Receive the action message from the button on the main thread, and then do only the actual work—if anything—on a secondary thread.

Note that showing the window will not block any other windows or anything else you're doing unless you specifically make it do so (i.e., use `runModalForWindow:`). If you show the window in the normal way, all your windows continue to work normally. Any timers and observers and similar things you've scheduled on the main thread also continue to work. You don't need to create threads or do anything else special for this; it all just works by default.

*If* the work that you'll eventually do may take a non-trivial amount of time, *then* you should put *that* on a secondary thread, only when it comes time to do it. You should also look into whether or not it'd be easier or better to construct as operation objects or blocks than as raw threads. It probably will.

Comment: UI stuff has to take place in a certain order which is serialized on the main thread, and it takes for granted its current state... so if you poke about from another thread... maybe nothing bad happens... but usually something really bad and hard to track down happens down the road somewhere...

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF) method, just in case the OP doesn't know how to call a method on the main thread.

Comment: @RobKeniger: In which case, it is also worth mentioning that stuff is on the main thread unless performed elsewhere (whether by manually creating threads or by using GCD or NSOperationQueue), and questioning whether the code shown in the question should be on another thread in the first place.